# Why don't Searchgasm page links work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins

I'm using the Searchgasm plugin for my searching and pagination.  Everything seems to work great but the page links don't seem to work at all.  Has anyone had this problem with Searchgasm before?

Controller Code:

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /artists
  # GET /artists.xml
  def index
    @search = Artist.new_search
    @search.per_page = 10
    @search.page = 2

    @artists = @search.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @artists }
    end
  end
end
```

View Code:

```
<h1>Listing artists</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th><%= :name %></th>
  </tr>

<% for artist in @artists %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to artist.name, artist %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_artist_path(artist) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', artist, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

Per page: <%= per_page_select %>
<br />
<br />
<% if @search.page_count > 1 %>
    <div class="pages"><%= page_links :spread => 1 %></div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'New artist', new_artist_path %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller should be:

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /artists
  # GET /artists.xml
  def index
    @search = Artist.new_search(params[:search])
    @artists = @search.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @artists }
    end
  end
end
```

The line:

```
@search = Artist.new_search(params[:search])
```

Grabs the parameters from the page link click to perform the search.